# Create a viewpager

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-viewpager

Im trying to create a viewpager. Currently i have an application where you press an item from a list, an image is displayed in fullscreen. When im in the new fragmentactivity (where the image is shown) i want to be able to swipe in order to display a new fragmentactivity.

Current code:

AndroidListViewActivity.java

```
public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] pihl_classes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pihl_classes);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, pihl_classes));

    ListView lv = getListView();

 // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          // selected item
          String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
          // sending data to new activity
          i.putExtra("product", product);
          startActivity(i);


      }
    });  
}
```

The SingleListItem.java looks like this:

```
public class SingleListItem extends FragmentActivity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

    ImageView productImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.product_image);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
    // displaying selected product image

    if (product.equals("ONE")) {
          productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.FISTIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("TWO")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.SECONDIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("THREE")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.THIRDIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("FOUR")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.FOURTHIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("FIVE")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.FIFTHIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("SIX")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.SIXTHIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("SEVEN")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.SEVENTHIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("EIGHT")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.EIGHTIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("NINE")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.NINTHIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("TEN")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.TENTHIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("ELEVEN")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ELEVENTHIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("TWELVE")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.TWELFTHIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("THIRTEEN")) {
            productImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.THIRTHEENTHIMAGE);
        }

}
```

Now i want to create a new fragment, to show something totally different, when you swipe to the right. To my understanding, this can be done with the viewpager, however im not sure how to implement the viewpager into my application. I tried to create a viewpager, and then use my SingleListItem as a fragment, but alot of errors occured. I have been reading lots of guides, cant seem to get it right anyway.

Simply: I click an item in my listview, an image is shown in fullscreen. In this scene i want to be able to swipe in order to display a new fragment. Which I will design later on. How do I add this feature?

Thanks.

Comment: From what i see above you are not trying to create a view pager, there is no view pager code, please could you add it

Comment: For a clear understanding of how to use a view pager: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Let me reformulate: I want to know where i add the viewpager, if it's in a new class, or if i sohuld add it in a current FragmentActivity.

 btw.I have read that, and it didnt make me much wiser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to create a `ViewPager` you need the following in your XML:

```
<!-- activity_screen_slide.xml -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Note that this comes with the v4 support library.

Then you need a `PagerAdapter` that will supply the pages to display. These will be fragments with your images. Once you figure out that logic, swiping will be taken care of for you by Android.

Documentation has a [detailed tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) for the same.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What i have to do is therefore: Create a new class, when i press an item in the listview, the newly created class is shown. Via a PagerAdapter, my SingleListItem.java file is supplied and the correct image is shown - depending on which item was clicked. Then i have to create a new ActivityFragment, where my new content goes, and supply it via my Adapter. Correct?

Comment: @Rasmus it owuld be a waste of effort to try to answer your questions here because what you are asking is already in the tutorial :)